# how do i see if a big JSON object contains a value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm using PHP to json encode a massive multi-dimensional array of events, so i get something like this:

```
var ents = {"7":{"event_id":"7","nn":"The Whisky Drifters","nn_url":"the-whisky-drifters",
  "venue":"The Grain Barge","date_num":"2010-06-11","date_txt":"Friday 11th June",
  "gig_club":"1","sd":"A New Acoustic String Band...","ven_id":"44",
  "art":0},"15":{"event_id":"15","nn":"Bass Kitchen","nn_url":"bass-kitchen",
  "venue":"Timbuk2","date_num":"2010-06-11","date_txt":"Friday 11th June",
  "gig_club":"2","sd":"Hexadecimal \/ DJ Derek \/ Id","ven_id":"21",
  "art":1},
```

the first dimension is the id, see

```
var ents = {"7":{
```

So it's possible to get the ids without examining the nested objects...

**What's the fastest, most efficient way to check if my JSON contains an id?**

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use the [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) method:

```
if (ents.hasOwnProperty('7')) {
  //..
}
```

This method checks if the object contains the specified property regardless of its value.

Is faster than the [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/in_Operator) operator because it doesn't checks for inherited properties.

Comment: @Haroldo, you want only to check if an specific id (first level property) exits right? or you want to extract all those property names?

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to what CMS said: If you need all properties, you can loop over the porperties with [`for ... in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/for...in):

```
for (prop in ents) {
  alert(prop); // Shows "7", "15", etc.
  // Accessing the sub-object:
  alert(ents[prop].nn); // Shows the names of each event
}
```

Also that isn't a "multi-dimensional array". It's an object (with more nested objects).

Comment: it was a multi-dimensional array when it was in PHP unless i'm mistaken

Answer (score 2):

yes it is possible but you have to loop through complete json object on client side.

```
var JSONobj = ents, yourid;
for(key in JSONobj)
{
   if(((typeof key) == 'number') && key==yourid )
         alert(key);
}
```

if you are using jQuery then you can use $.each method to fetchng keys from jsonObject

```
   var JSONobj = ents, yourid;
        $.each(JSONobj, function(key, value){     
             if(((typeof key) == 'number') && key==yourid )
                 alert(key);
           //ids.push(key);
        });
```

Comment: would it be more efficient to check if the value is an integer before seeing if it matches my query id, or do you think im better having a separate object just of ids?

Comment: you could add both checks in one line i.e if(((typeof key) == 'number') && key == yourid) then you wont need an array to hold all ids.

Answer (score -1):

Just use `myObject.has("keyName")`. This is what really works.

Comment: Nope! Object.has is not a function. Just tried it, and MDN doesn't mention it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object So it's not "what really works".