# Check if object contains property with specific value

Tags: javascript

I have an object like below:

```
var _obj = { 
    'name1@gmail.com' : { 
        'bob@gmail.com' : {
            channel: 'V2231212', 
            from: 'bob'
        },
        'judy@gmail.com' : {
            channel: 'V223231212', 
            from: 'judy'
        }
    },
    'name2@gmail.com' : { 
        'bill@gmail.com' : {
            channel: 'V123123',
            from: 'bill'
        }
    }
};
```

How can i check to see if anywhere in the object a "`channel`" exists that is equal to "`V123123`" ?

In the above case bill@gmail is equal to V123123 and should return true.

Any ideas?

Comment: [whathaveyoutried.com](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I have no idea where to start :/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021206/how-do-i-see-if-a-big-json-object-contains-a-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
console.log(containsPropertyValue(_obj, 'channel', 'V123123'));

function containsPropertyValue(obj, propertyName, propertyValue){
    var contains = false;
    function a(o){
        for(var prop in o)
            if(o.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
                if(prop === propertyName && o[prop] === propertyValue){
                    contains = true;
                    return;
                }
                if(typeof o[prop] === 'object')
                    a(o[prop]);
            }
    }
    a(_obj);
    return contains;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dHS5a/2/)

Comment: I would put the own property test in the `if` block, not a separate block.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution

```
Object.keys(_obj).forEach(function(v, i){
  Object.keys(_obj[v]).forEach(function(w, k){
    if(_obj[v][w].hasOwnProperty('channel')&&_obj[v][w]['channel']=='V123123')
      return true;
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative using [**getOwnPropertyNames**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames)

```
function hasPropertyWithValue(obj, propertyName, propertyValue) {
    var matchFound = false;
    var _prop;
    var _properties = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj);

    for(var i = 0; i < _properties.length; i++){
        _prop = _properties[i];

        if(_prop === propertyName && obj[_prop] === propertyValue){
            return true;
        }

        if(typeof obj[_prop] === 'object'){
            matchFound = hasPropertyWithValue(obj[_prop],  propertyName, propertyValue);
            if (matchFound){
               return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return matchFound;
}
```

Used like this:

```
var matched = hasPropertyWithValue(_obj, 'channel', 'V123123');
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4sKdr/) - Using `getOwnPropertyNames()`

---

---

`getOwnPropertyNames()` Browser Support

---

- Firefox (Gecko)    : 4 (2.0)
- Chrome             : 5
- Internet Explorer  : 9
- Opera              : 12
- Safari             : 5